# Знак между тому и  кому.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Имей совесть, нельзя так поступать с теми()кому ты дорог.

Ставится ли запятая перед "кому"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ставится, конечно. С союзного слова "кому" начинается придаточное предложение.